# How to re-allow my app to use the current location

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager to find the location.The first time that I run the app for mistake I didn't allow the app to use the current location.
So every time the delegate gets notified through the locationManager:didFailWithError selector.
I tried to make a clean build and to delete the project folder in derived data, but it still doesn't ask me to use the current location.
I would make possibile to re-select through that panel if I would use the location, how is that possibile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the application from the simulator or phone and then run another build onto the device.

Comment: How to do that? I'm using the iPhone simulator on os x.

Comment: Just like you would on a device, in the simulator, click and hold down  on the icon of your application, when it starts to wiggle, release the click and click on the x on its conner.  Another thing you can do is just clear out your simulator settings, when the simulator is the window that has focus, click iOS simulator -> reset content and settings located on the top bar of your mac screen.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly, if I think that this is not a coding issue:
If you are on iOS6, you'll have to allow location services for the app at

> Settings > Privacy > Location Services.

For more info, see Apple's documentation here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5467?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: But I'm just using the simulator.